# as well as provided/providing

Tags: grammar

I think it is a frequently asked question, but I could not get the right answer, so I am posting it here.

> Also, the author created dark tone as well as
>   provided/providing many instances of death.

Some people say that I SHOULD use parallel form, but some people say I HAVE TO use gerund from. Which one is correct, provided or providing??

Answer (score 0):

Start by simplifying this sentence.

**Option 1:**

*The author created as well as provided.*

**Option 2:**

*The author created as well as providing.*

Or to emphasize it even more, replace *as well as* with *and*:

*The author created and providing.*

Clearly, option 2 makes no sense. You have to go with option 1 - *provided*.

However, you could modify the sentence to make it work with gerund:

*The author created tone by providing instances*

*The author created tone providing instances*